# Combining two different sql statements into one

Tags: sql, oracle

I work for a warehouse for a popular retailer in the UK. I need to write an SQL statement that gives me the total number of pick locations between a given range AND the total number of empty locations between the same range.

I have managed to write queries for each but I don't know how to write them in the same query.

The first is the total number of locations.

```
SELECT lh.aisle, count(lh.aisle)
FROM locn_hdr lh
WHERE   lh.LOCN_CLASS = 'A'
AND     lh.BAY BETWEEN '0030' AND '0230'
AND     lh.PICK_DETRM_ZONE LIKE 'HG%'
AND     lh.AISLE <= 'QA'
GROUP BY lh.AISLE
ORDER BY lh.AISLE;
```

This gives the following results.

```
Aisle   Count of Locations   
I1      164
IA      164
IB      164
IC      164
ID      164
```

etc.... There is a long list of aisles so I've only shown the first 5.

The second SQL is

```
SELECT  lh.AISLE, COUNT(lh.AISLE)
FROM    LOCN_HDR lh
LEFT OUTER JOIN wm_inventory wi ON wi.location_id = lh.locn_id AND wi.on_hand_qty > '0'
WHERE   lh.LOCN_CLASS = 'A'
AND     lh.BAY BETWEEN '0030' AND '0230'
AND     lh.PICK_DETRM_ZONE LIKE 'HG%'
AND     lh.AISLE <= 'QA'
AND     wi.location_id IS NULL
GROUP BY lh.AISLE
ORDER BY lh.AISLE;
```

The results for this are:

```
Aisle   Count of Empties
I1      17
IA      54
IB      53
IC      46
ID      38
```

The table I want is:

```
Aisle   Count Of locations   Count of Empties
I1      164                  17
IA      164                  54
```

I'm hoping there is an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method would be to use `EXISTS` with a subquery in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT lh.aisle, count(lh.aisle) as cnt1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                             FROM wm_inventory wi 
                             WHERE wi.location_id = lh.locn_id AND wi.on_hand_qty > 0
                THEN 1 ELSE 0
            END) as cnt2
FROM locn_hdr lh
WHERE lh.LOCN_CLASS = 'A' AND 
      lh.BAY BETWEEN '0030' AND '0230' AND
      lh.PICK_DETRM_ZONE LIKE 'HG%' AND
      lh.AISLE <= 'QA'
GROUP BY lh.AISLE
ORDER BY lh.AISLE;
```

Note:  I am guessing that `on_hand_qty` is a number; hence, I removed the the single quotes from `'0'`.  Numbers should be compared to numbers; strings to strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep working with your query, you wasn't far from the actual solution. Just add conditional aggregation using `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
SELECT  lh.AISLE,
        COUNT(lh.AISLE) as cnt1,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN wi.location_id IS NULL THEN 1 END) as cnt2
FROM    LOCN_HDR lh
LEFT OUTER JOIN wm_inventory wi ON wi.location_id = lh.locn_id AND wi.on_hand_qty > '0'
WHERE   lh.LOCN_CLASS = 'A'
AND     lh.BAY BETWEEN '0030' AND '0230'
AND     lh.PICK_DETRM_ZONE LIKE 'HG%'
AND     lh.AISLE <= 'QA'
GROUP BY lh.AISLE
ORDER BY lh.AISLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a straightforward variation on your second query gives the answer you require?

```
SELECT  lh.AISLE
        , COUNT(lh.AISLE) total_aisles
        , sum(case when wi.location_id IS NULL then 1 else 0 end) empty_aisles
FROM    LOCN_HDR lh
LEFT OUTER JOIN wm_inventory wi ON wi.location_id = lh.locn_id AND wi.on_hand_qty > 0
WHERE   lh.LOCN_CLASS = 'A'
AND     lh.BAY BETWEEN '0030' AND '0230'
AND     lh.PICK_DETRM_ZONE LIKE 'HG%'
AND     lh.AISLE <= 'QA'     
GROUP BY lh.AISLE
ORDER BY lh.AISLE;
```